# Maven is telling me that I have an AMD64 processor. I'm most definitely using an Intel processor. What's going on?

Tags: java, maven

[image: command line prompt in Windows 7]

A quick **`maven -ver`** query shows that I have an amd64 processor, but I am most certainly running an i7 as shown in my system specifications... Any ideas as to why this may happen? I considered that perhaps it may have something to do with an incorrectly installed JDK, but I don't believe that's the case...

[image]

Comment: The instruction set is x86_64 (which was invented by AMD, hence AMD64), at the time Intel was pushing Itanium.

Comment: That just means you're using a 64bit processor. Both Intel and AMD 64 bit processors show up the same

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 64-bit extensions used in modern x86 processors from Intel and AMD were developed by AMD when Intel was promoting a competing architecture, IA-64. AMD's [x86-64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64) architecture gained greater mainstream popularity due to its backward compatibility with the legacy x86 architecture, and eventually Intel implemented AMD's 64-bit instruction set.  Some software still calls this architecture "amd64" but this is independent of which brand CPU you have.

Answer (score 3):

Maven is not telling that you have an AMD processor. The `arch` field is about processor **architecture**, not brand. The prefix `amd` before `64` is used to differentiate from the `x64`, which [totally different](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64) from `x86`.

Answer (score 0):

The 64 bit architecture commonly used is **known as `amd64`** because it's the design promoted by AMD (and  **also adopted Intel**).

The original 64 bit design by Intel is known as `ia64` for Itanium architecture - and is pretty much nonexistant today.

I'm pretty sure Wikipedia can tell you more about this, if you search.